# Recover Postgresql pgBarman

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, barman

I've setup a postgresql DB and I want to backup it.

I've 1 server with my main DB et 1 with Barman.
All the setup is working, I can backup my DB with barman.

I just don't understand how I can recover my DB on a exact time point between the backups that I do everyday.

```
barman@ubuntu:~$ barman check main-db-server
WARNING: No backup strategy set for server 'main-db-server' (using default 'exclusive_backup').
WARNING: The default backup strategy will change to 'concurrent_backup' in the future. Explicitly set 'backup_options' to silence this warning.
Server main-db-server:
        PostgreSQL: OK
        is_superuser: OK
        wal_level: OK
        directories: OK
        retention policy settings: OK
        backup maximum age: OK (interval provided: 1 day, latest backup age: 9 minutes, 59 seconds)
        compression settings: OK
        failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
        minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 6 backups, expected at least 0)
        ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
        not in recovery: OK
        systemid coherence: OK (no system Id available)
        archive_mode: OK
        archive_command: OK
        continuous archiving: OK
        archiver errors: OK
```

And when I backup my DB

```
barman@ubuntu:~$ barman backup main-db-server
WARNING: No backup strategy set for server 'main-db-server' (using default 'exclusive_backup').
WARNING: The default backup strategy will change to 'concurrent_backup' in the future. Explicitly set 'backup_options' to silence this warning.
Starting backup using rsync-exclusive method for server main-db-server in /var/lib/barman/main-db-server/base/20210427T150505
Backup start at LSN: 0/1C000028 (00000005000000000000001C, 00000028)
Starting backup copy via rsync/SSH for 20210427T150505
Copy done (time: 2 seconds)
Asking PostgreSQL server to finalize the backup.
Backup size: 74.0 MiB. Actual size on disk: 34.9 KiB (-99.95% deduplication ratio).
Backup end at LSN: 0/1C0000C0 (00000005000000000000001C, 000000C0)
Backup completed (start time: 2021-04-27 15:05:05.289717, elapsed time: 11 seconds)
Processing xlog segments from file archival for main-db-server
        00000005000000000000001B
        00000005000000000000001C
        00000005000000000000001C.00000028.backup
```

I don't know how to restore my DB on a time between 2 backups :/

Thanks

Comment: Did you do what the docs (http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.12/#recover) say? Did it not work? What went wrong?

Comment: Yeah. I've Backup my DB, I add things an delete other. When I want to go back to the time just before I delete the data that doesn't work. It go back at the time of the backup even if I choose a specific --target-time

Comment: It works for me.  What was in barman_wal directory before you started the new/restored server? What was in the recovery.conf?  What log messages do you get when you start it up?